# How to create a readable view object based on two tables having both inner and outer joins

Tags: oracle-adf

I have Table1 having a1,a2,a3,a4 fields and Table2 having b1,b2,b3,b4 fileds.

Join:
inner join Table1.a1=Table2.b2 AND outer join Table1.a3=Table2.b3
How could I create Entity based VO having these both inner and outer joins?

Answer (score 1):

You can try modifying the generated query by hand (custom query), after you create the VO based on both EO's in the traditional way.

Comment: but ADF wont let me modify complete query. We can only modify 'where' clause alone. Let me know if I am wrong :)

Comment: Open the code in source mode and do modifications from over there.
Just make sure you are not editing this VO in design mode anymore, you will have to edit the Source  from now on.

Comment: Thats cool, but I am afraid doing so, may corrupt file. Won't it?

Comment: You are having a crazy requirement already :).
In theory it should work, as long as you stop using JDeveloper design mode on this VO alone.

Comment: Bad news:(. Modifying source xml file is corrupting its corresponding sql query. So I think its not right approach. Can creating 2VO's with 1 VO containing Inner join and other VO with outer join. And finally establishing View Link between those VO's can solve my problem?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this one please: "Modifying source xml file is corrupting its corresponding sql query." What exactly do you see as corrupted?

Comment: For Every join created in VO, its configuration is described <Entity Usage > tag. So I tried to  explicitly create another <Entity Usage> tag for describing second join. This led to some disturbances in its sql query. Anyways, my problem is resolved by using 2 viewlinks between Table1 and Table 2